# Unable to rename permalink

Tags: permalinks

I have a custom content type, `'Events'`. I'm unable to rename the slug of one event from `'2010-2'` to `'2010'`. There are 6 or 7 other entries of the same content type and they're all fine.

Here's what I've done:

- Verified no items in the Trash (for every content type, just to be sure)
- Manually removed drafts, autosaves and revisions from the database
- Verified that no other existing piece of content has `2010` in its slug

**EDIT**
Worth noting that "`/events/2010`" actually redirects to "`/events/2010-2`"

Comment: Why can't you just manually rename it? When editing the post, you should be able to click "edit" in the permalink field and edit it. You're not able to do that?

Comment: I had this problem once and wound up forcing the slug to be set as the one I wanted on save using a db query. Unfortunately I do not have the code in front of me right now. I would not recommend it anyway as it is a dirty hack.

Comment: did you check thoroughly the table wp_posts? the attachments also have slugs. also check post_content **and** guid columns, might have something using "2010"

Comment: @Aliyah Sure I can do that, but it renames it right back to '2010-2' as if there were a duplicate.

Comment: @peteroak Literally spent a half hour querying almost every column in the damn DB for '2010'

Comment: For sure you have missed something. Your site will only add -2 if there is an original somewhere. Try making sure everything is gone and permanently deleted again

Comment: that sounds **thoroughly** to me. could it be a clash with your permalinks? like if you're using /%year%/...

Comment: Is your mod rewrite working?

Comment: @peteroak My permalinks are set to /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/, but again (1) all other events are named similarly with years and all of them work fine, and (2) the rewriting of the 'Event' content type is at '/event', not the root of the site.

Comment: Just verified that '-2' is being added to the end of WHATEVER I put in for the slug. The plot thickens.

Comment: Seems to work with everything other than integers in the slug field, so I have a feeling that I'm battling with some internal stuff having to do with custom post type archives (even though I have 'has_archive' specifically set to false?). Solved for now by renaming the permalinks.

Comment: by the way, care to show us your custom post functions? i'm intrigued too.

Comment: @peteroak Here's the 'Event' type in question: http://cl.ly/image/3p162O1O013N

Answer (score 1):

Items left in your trash will directly affect new permalinks being appended with -$N.

Comment: _Verified no items in the Trash_ he said he did.

Comment: I know he said he did, I read that.  But humans often err. :-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BrianFegter The author thinks that posts in the trash do affect the permalink generation. I don't know if this happens, but I leave it as "Looks good" during review.

Comment: @kaiser You're right. Edited and upvoted this answer.